Is there a way to configure a vscode launch config to run python code based on the command line args I use to run it manually
I currently run code for a project I'm working on with python using the following example command line in my workspace folder for the project.
    python -m testing.test_file
This is because my project files are setup something like this;
    project_folder
    ├───src
    |   ├───__init__.py
    │   ├───main_class.py
    |   └───utils.py
    |
    └───testing
        ├───__init__.py
        ├───test_file.py
        └───main.py

and src file contains various python files that are imported in main.py and test_file.py for example.
I have tried modifying the vscode launch.json file by changing program to ${workspacefold} and adding the args "-m testing.test_file" but it always either can't find the file or runs it can find the imports because it is running from wrong directory.
While it is fine running it using the simple command line I use currently, I wanted to try to get it working with the debugger in vscode etc rather than print debuging.

Do you also set the working directory "cwd": "project_folder"? Can you include your launch.json?

It looks like this;
{     "version": "0.2.0",     "configurations": [         {             "name": "Python Debugger: Current File with Arguments",             "type": "debugpy",             "request": "launch",             "program": "${workspaceFolder}",             "console": "integratedTerminal",             "args": " -m testing.test_file",             "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"         }     ] }

"args" is supposed to be a list like "args": ["arg1", "arg2", etc]. But in this case you actually need to set the "program" like "program": "${workspaceFolder}/testing/test_file.py"

That did not work, it can't find the modules again.
Although with your help I found that setting "program":"" and "args":["-m", "${command:pickArgs}"]. I can run it and just enter testing.test_file as the argument and it runs normally. Is there no way for it to figure out the argument based on what file im running.

If you want it to run the current file you could do "args": ["-m", "${file}"]

I ended up using a launch.json environment file which looked like this:
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Launch",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "args": ["-m", "${relativeFileDirname}.${fileBasenameNoExtension}"],
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
        },
    ]
}


Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

You could try to add a .env file including the PYTHONPATH under your workspace.
Then add "python.envFile": "${workspaceFolder}/.env", to your settings.json.
